# Very simple tutorial example of D3.js not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm kind of new to D3.js. I'm reading *Getting Started with D3* by Mike Dewar. I tried the very first example in the book, and it doesn't work. I've been tearing my hear out over this. What is wrong with my code here?

In the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>
   function draw(data) {
    "use strict";
   d3.select("body")
      .append("ul")
      .selectAll("li")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("li")
         .text(function (d) {
            return d.name + ": " + d.status;
         });
      }
</script>
```

In the `<body>`:

```
<script>

    d3.json("flare.json", draw);

</script>
```

And the JSON file:

```
[
{
    "status": ["GOOD SERVICE"],
    "name": ["123"],
    "url": [null],
    "text": ["..."],
    "plannedworkheadline": [null],
    "Time": [" 7:35AM"],
    "Date": ["12/15/2011"]
}
]
```

Comment: Try changing the script include to: <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>?

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I think those are just two URLs to the same files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, it may prevent you from opening the file properly because of cross domain security restrictions. Try Firefox to see if that's the case (it will probably let you load the file correctly).

If that is the problem, you will want to install a local web server like WAMP (if you're running Windows) or follow instructions on the wiki page here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

Good luck

Comment: Weird. I thought I had already tried that, but when I tried again, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Good to get a result!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your browser console to see if your XHR request
was successful?

When I attempt to run the code on my machine, 
with a local version of d3 (v3) in VS 2012 Express, 
the XHR request comes back with an error message:

**HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found**

However, when I change the extension of the "flare"
file from **.json** to **.txt** or **.js**, as alluded to here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/39989/iis-cant-serve-certain-file-extension, 
then the XHR request succeeds.

Comment: I checked the console and the script only returns the opening and closing `ul` tags. I tried changing the file extension, without success. However, in the past I've managed to retrieve json data in D3 by using an anonymous function, as such `d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {...`. I'm utterly confused.

Comment: Thanks for this. Forgot that IIS doesn't serve any weird file type out of the box (i.e. .topojson).

Answer (score 0):

Well d.name and d.status are both arrays and should be just strings if you want to show their contents or yo should be accessing the 0 index value of those arrays;  I.e., d.name[0] + ':' + d.status[0];

Answer (score 0):

It might be your JSON. I did the same exercise, and it worked fine. Here is my js(I appended to a div, not body). I'm running a local web server.

```
d3.json("data/mta001.json", drawli);

function drawli(data) {
    "use strict";
    d3.select('#mta001')
      .append('ul')
      .selectAll('ul')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('li')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name + ': ' + d.status;
      });
    d3.selectAll('#mta001 li')
      .style('color', function (d) {
        if ( d.status == 'GOOD SERVICE') {
            return 'green';
        } else {
            return 'fuchsia';
        }
      });
}
```

and here is my JSON:

```
[
        {
          "name": "123",
          "status": "DELAYS",
          "text": "delay text",
          "Date": "12/08/2012",
          "Time": " 1:03PM"
        }
]
```