# Simple D3 tutorial not appearing

Tags: d3.js

Used code from this tutorial:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245#index.html

Saved `index.html`

Saved `data.tsv` into the same directory

First, I tried opening the html by itself.  That showed a blank web page (viewing the page source showed the code was indeed there).

Then, I ran `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &` in the directory (although I should not have needed this step).  It showed a blank web page as well.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

How do I get d3 working?  Thanks

Comment: Hi, did the same and works for me. I downloaded the gist from [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3883245). Any error messages showing in the java console?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Actually it was a silly mistake on my part.  I renamed the .tsv file and forgot to reflect that change in the code.  It appears now.  Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. The tutorial does not show up. I downloaded the files from gist where the index.html and data.tsv are in the same directory. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just forgot that I renamed a file.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, if you cannot get it to work you need to check your browser. The above tutorial did not work for me in Safari or Chrome on a mac but worked in **Firefox**. I got this information from here:

> [Very simple tutorial example of D3.js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721945/very-simple-tutorial-example-of-d3-js-not-working)

and here:

> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki